# Subir y guardar imagen PHP

Tags: php, http-post

Tengo un problema al subir imágenes al servidor, solo se deben actualizar las imágenes de la tabla si se marca un checkbox, sino guarda el valor anterior

la base de datos solo guarda el nombre de la imagen asociada

**Form.html**

```
<form name ="dormUpdate" class="form" method="post" action="update.php" align="center">

    <div align="center"></div>
    <div class="info" align="center">
        <fieldset>
            <p> Producto </p>
            <label for="id"> <input id="id"   value="<?php echo $id; ?>"      type="hidden"   name="id" />
            <label for="imagen_chica"> <span>Imagen Chica:  </span>  <input id="imagen_chica"   value="<?php echo 'No Change'; ?>"   type="file"     name="imagen_chica"  /></label><br>
            <label for="changed1"> <span>Cambiar:  </span>  <input id="changed1"     type="checkbox"     name="changed1"  /></label><br>
            <label for="imagen_grande"> <span>Imagen Grande:</span>  <input id="imagen_grande"  value="<?php echo 'No Change'; ?>"   type="file"     name="imagen_grande" /></label><br>
            <label for="changed2"> <span>Cambiar:  </span>  <input id="changed2"     type="checkbox"     name="changed2"  /></label><br>
        </fieldset></form>
```

**update.php**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
require "funciones.php";
$ch1      = 0;
$ch2      = 0;
$img_ch   = 'NOT SET';
$img_gr   = 'NOT SET';

$con      = conecta();
$id       = $_REQUEST['id'];
$ch1      = $_REQUEST['changed1'];
$ch2      = $_REQUEST['changed2'];



$target_path = './fotos';
$img1path = $target_path .  $_FILES['imagen_chica']['name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen_chica']['tmp_name'], $img1path))
{
    $img_ch = $_FILES['imagen_chica']['name'];
 }

$img2path = $target_path . $_FILES['imagen_grande']['name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen_grande']['tmp_name'], "$img2path"))
{
    $img_gr = $_FILES['imagen_grande']['name'];
}


$res = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id = $id;");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) ;
$img_1orig    = $row['imagen_chica'];
$img_2orig    = $row['imagen_grande'];

if($ch1 != "on"){
    $img_gr = $img_1orig;
}
if($ch2 != "on"){
    $img_ch = $img_2orig;
}


$res = mysqli_query($con,
                    "UPDATE productos SET
                            imagen_chica  = '$img_ch',
                            imagen_grande = '$img_gr'
                            WHERE id      =  $id;"
);
```

/////////////////////////////

Comment: Has probado en añadir el atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"` a tu formulario, ya que es necesario para el funcionamiento de carga de archivos.

Comment: Gracias, ahora la ruta se esta guardando en la base de datos, pero no aparece la imagen,  la esta guardando junto al codigo, no en fotos

y el tiutlo e la imagen se cambia por fotos+noombre.jpg

Comment: Prueba modificando la *ruta* añadiendo `/` al final, quedaría así: `$target_path = './fotos/';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está que se te ha olvidado el atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Este valor es necesario cuando se utilizan formularios que tienen un control de carga de archivos

> **Nota:** El atributo `enctype` sólo se puede utilizarse si usamos `method = "post"`.

**Ejemplo:**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

El segundo error esta en tu ruta, debes añadir al final `/`.

**Ejemplo:**

```
$target_path = './fotos/';
```